Is there a way to create a custom collation in PostgreSQL 11?
I have a PostgreSQL 11.22 database, and I need TEXT columns in some tables to be able to store and sort strings in different languages.
The encoding is on UTF8, and it works, all different language character sets I need are correctly stored and retrieved. I have been testing if the current collation (en_US) works for the languages we need to support, and so far it correctly sorts text in the languages we need except for polish and czech.
Polish was an easy solution for now, we can specify the polish collation when we have any ORDER BY, and it works. However, there is no czech collation that I can see in the pg_catalog. I have worked with later PostgreSQL, and I know it is possible to create custom collations. However, reading the documentation, I can't find any mention of this for version 11.22 (which is unsupported).
Is there any workaround? I think another solution would be to import the collation, which is what I've seen suggested online, but I don't know how to accomplish this on Postgres, or if there is a list of the collations in the libc library where I could see how the collation I need is even called, to be able to import it.

Read Collation support: 23.2.2.2.1. libc Collations. FYI. Postgres 11 is 1 year past EOL, you should plan on updating in the near future.

If you don't have a Czech C library collation in pg_collation, first create it on the operating system. Depending on your distribution, you might have to install some glibc language packs or run locale-gen cs_CZ.UTF-8 or something similar.
Once you have the C library locale on your operating system, restart PostgreSQL and import it as superuser with
SELECT pg_import_system_collations('pg_catalog');

The alternative is to use an ICU collation, if your PostgreSQL is compiled with ICU support. The Czech ICU collation would be called "cs-CZ-x-icu".
